# how can i change "minimum_waypoint_count"

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can i change default value of "minimum_waypoint_count" or other parameters
"rosparam set /move_group/ompl/minimum_waypoint_count 100" has no effect.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399551/how-can-i-change-%22minimum_waypoint_count%22/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in "move_group.launch" file

```
<param name="planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene_hz" value="100.0" />
<param name="ompl/minimum_waypoint_count" value="20.0" />
```

---

Originally posted by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) with karma: 31 on 2022-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0